# Push notification in parse

Tags: android-studio, parse-platform

I have uploaded my cloud code function to back4app and in my android studio i call the cloud function but it will return invalid function please help me.

Cloud code function in back4app server

```
Parse.Cloud.define('push', function (req, res)
{
    Parse.Push.send(
    {
        alert: req.params.alert;
        data: req.params.data;
    },
    {
        success: function (result)
        {
            res.success(result);
        },
        error: function ()
        {
            res.error("Nothing here");
        }
    });
});
```

my call back function in android studio

```
HashMap < String, Object > params = new HashMap < String, Object > ();
params.put("data", data);
params.put("alert", "User " + email + " Liked " + getnaeofcommenter + "                              comment");
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("push", params, new FunctionCallback < Object > ()
{@
    Override
    public void done(Object o, ParseException e)
    {
        if (e == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Push notification sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            e.getMessage().toString();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For what I know about push notifications, usually the "alert" needs to be placed inside "data". As you can see on Parse's documentation on Pushes:

> If you want to send more than just a message, you can set other fields in the data dictionary. There are some reserved fields that have a special meaning.
>
> alert: the notification’s message.
>
> badge: (iOS only) the value indicated in the top right corner of the app icon. This can be set to a value or to Increment in order to increment the current value by 1.
>
> sound: (iOS only) the name of a sound file in the application bundle.
>
> content-available: (iOS only) If you are a writing an app using the Remote Notification Background Mode introduced in iOS7 (a.k.a. “Background Push”), set this value to 1 to trigger a background download.
>
> category: (iOS only) the identifier of the UNNotification​Category for this push notification.
>
> uri: (Android only) an optional field that contains a URI. When the notification is opened, an Activity associated with opening the URI is launched.
>
> title: (Android, Windows 8, & Windows Phone 8 only) the value displayed in the Android system tray or Windows 8 toast notification.

So, for your Cloud Code, maybe you should arrange it like this:

```
Parse.Push.send({
  data: {
    alert: req.params.alert;
  }
}, {
  success: function(result) {
    res.success(result);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    res.error("Nothing here");
  }
});
```

All that info can be found on [Parse's Javascript Documentation](http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#sending-options).